# Reject certain external OpenIdConnect Authentication Attempts

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, authentication, openid-connect, claims

I have multiple external OpenIdConnect Login Providers in my system.

However, I do not want to trust any external login provider a 100%.
So we want to define certain rules by looking at the received claims from the login provider.

And for example only allow certain email addresses to be authenticated by certain login providers.

Here is an example of what I was thinking about:

```cs
builder.AddOpenIdConnect(
   authenticationScheme: clientId,
   displayName: displayName,
   options =>
   {
      // ....

      var allowedEmailDomains = openIdConnectLoginProvider["AllowedEmailDomains"]?.Split(',');

      if (allowedEmailDomains != null && allowedEmailDomains.Any())
      {
         options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
         {
            OnUserInformationReceived = async (context) =>
            { 
               ThrowIfEmailDomainIsNotAllowed(/* ... */);
            }
         }
      }
   });
```

It works, but I am not sure this is the correct way of dealing with that kind of business.

Is there some kind of method call on the context object to indicate that this authentication should not be allowed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to reject the authentication attempt:

```cs
OnUserInformationReceived = async (context) =>
{
    // ...
    context.Fail("Email not allowed.");
}
```